# Switch one column to Another

Tags: r

I have a very basic question, but I'm new to R so would appreciate any help.

I have a column (among other columns) in one dataset which the rows read as numeric codes(for example).

In another dataset, I have two columns, one is the numeric codes (same as above) and the column next to it are names.

Is there a way in R that I can rename the numeric codes in the first datasets to the names using the second dataset as a reference essentially?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You want to use either `merge` (base R) or `left_join` (in package `dplyr`).

Comment: I've had a look at "left_join" but I think it can't be done if the columns are in different datasets. Or I don't know how to do it if it is possible.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so, it's customary to "accept" the answer by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(42)       # because I use `sample`, o/w unnecessary
df1 <- data.frame(n = sample(5, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ n: int  5 5 2 5 4 3 4 1 4 4

df2 <- data.frame(n = 1:5, txt = LETTERS[5:9], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ n  : int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ txt: chr  "E" "F" "G" "H" ...
```

Base R use of `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "n")
#    n txt
# 1  1   E
# 2  2   F
# 3  3   G
# 4  4   H
# 5  4   H
# 6  4   H
# 7  4   H
# 8  5   I
# 9  5   I
# 10 5   I
```

Notice that the order of `df1` is not preserved. We can use `merge(..., sort = FALSE)`, but the order is "unspecified" ([`?merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html)).

Using `dplyr::left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "n")
#    n txt
# 1  5   I
# 2  5   I
# 3  2   F
# 4  5   I
# 5  4   H
# 6  3   G
# 7  4   H
# 8  1   E
# 9  4   H
# 10 4   H
```

(Order is preserved.)